# MySQL Lock Graph

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, graphviz

We're working on improving our query interdependencies, and have found that occasionally there will be deadlocks that keep recurring. Does anyone know of a program that can generate a lock graph from the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS?

Comment: I tried to find visualization tool some time ago, without success. You can paste output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS here. I think I can help you.

Comment: I can read it well enough, but I was hoping for something that could just display a graph of locking interactions without having to write one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MySQL Monitoring Plugin` for Cacti or Nagios from `Percona`. It records `SHOW INNODB STATUS` results and makes them as graphs periodically that (maybe) you want.

Cacti : http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-plugins/cacti/mysql-templates.html

Nagios : http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-plugins/nagios/pmp-check-mysql-innodb.html